# does the Windows 10 upgrade-in-place wipe out your Users folder?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I had Win7 Pro. I upgraded it to Win 10. Now I go to C:\Users\MyName and the folder is essentially empty. Did the upgrade tool move my files? If so, where?

The size on disk of C:\Users\MyName is 1.06GB but I can't find any folders inside of it that are over 80kb. Something is fishy. I checked with WinDirStat and the largest folders in c:\users are all AppData. No documents.

My backups of the users folder are 4.1GB compressed, so it appears that the upgrade wiped my Users folder out. And didn't tell me. Further evidence, from an MS website: on the MS site it says "in ***most*** cases you’ll be able to keep your Windows settings, personal files, and most apps when you upgrade to Windows 10.".

Luckily I have a backup but this is just weird. It seems like the upgrade tool moved my files but didn't tell me where they went.

Comment: Is there any other folder under `C:\Users\` that might be your profile? For example, if you switched to a Microsoft account (which Win7 doesn't support) when you installed Win10, then it might have created a new profile directory and moved your files to the new folder.

Comment: No, the largest folder in there is my folder but the only thing that has any real filespace used is AppData.

Comment: The only reason the upgrade would "wipe" your user profiles is if you choose not to "keep everything".  I suggest you roll back to Windows 7 this assume you have not already ran that tool that wiped your previous installation of Windows.

Comment: I'm telling you that a) I didn't uncheck the "keep" option b) I don't recall even seeing the "keep" option and c) my Users\MyName\Documents folder is now completely empty. How would rolling back fix that? MS even says that it will keep docs in _most_ cases. So it appears I have encountered an edge case.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit due to your question changing:**

Use **[WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/)** to see where the big files are on your hard drive. Should show you what's going on with your user folder showing 1.06GB when it appears empty.

[image]

---

**Old Answer:**

In your `C:\` drive, there should be a folder called `Windows.old`. That's where your old install is, and files.

This of course only works if you selected to keep personal files when upgrading:

[image]

Comment: Documents folder there is empty.

Comment: Then you [didn't select to keep personal files](http://i.imgur.com/EnNgYQJ.png).

Comment: Highly unlikely that I would have unchecked that and forgotten.

Comment: Okay well you've since _changed your question_ to saying that your user folder says it's 1.06GB when it's really empty. This could be a different issue.

Comment: I didn't "change" the question -- I added information. The only thing that has any files really is AppData. Also, on the MS site it says "in most cases you’ll be able to keep your Windows settings, personal files, and most apps when you upgrade to Windows 10." Most cases. Great.

Comment: I edited my answer, try WinDirStat.

Comment: You must be taking me the wrong way. I don't particularly care at all